# Any text editor with version control online

Tags: dropbox, text-editors, version-control

I have a text file on my desktop which gets synced with Dropbox.

Are there any services like Dropbox which have a version control system so that I can see the history of all changes made, not just the current version of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client side GUI for Subversion, http://tortoisesvn.net might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Tortoise is a great program that I would highly recommend, but I'm pretty sure it has to be used with a repository. Tortoise by itself doesn't save the files.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of revision control repository would allow that (like [BeanStalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com), [GitHub](https://github.com/), or [Kenai](http://kenai.com/)).

The caveat there being that the repository is typically free as long as it's public. If you need the file to be private, you'll have to pay some sort of monthly/yearly fee.

Comment: but i want auto sync like drop box does . i have one text file for general note taking

Answer (score -2):

Here you go: draft (https://draftin.com/)

His blog is good (inspired reads): http://ninjasandrobots.com

Comment: Please read [answer] before answering. Don't just link, include a complete solution.